# Why can't you overload the '.' operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It would be very useful to be able to overload the . operator in C++ and return a reference to an object.

You can overload `operator->` and `operator*` but not `operator.`

Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: Can you give an example of when you want to override the '.' operator?

Comment: Generally, the use case is "smart references". A kind of Proxy.

Comment: @Gamecat: Read through [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1671.pdf) proposal to add the ability to overload `operator.` and `operator.*`, it has a few examples.

Comment: But you can't overload `->` or `*` on pointers!

Comment: how do you overload on pointers ? the overloading is with respect to the class, not the instances(objects) so at the time of overloading, we don't know if you are going to make pointers or not

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Spaces around `.` are allowed, so perhaps some clever but appalling dynamic dispatch hack that allows for expressing dot product as `matrix1 . matrix2`.

Comment: ["Operator Dot", proposal by Stroustrup and Dos Reis](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf)

Comment: Here's a later version of the Stroustrup/Dos Reis Operator Dot proposal: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf

Comment: Here's a competing proposal for solving many of the same problems, which tries to use a special form of inheritance instead of overloading the dot operator: https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0352r1.pdf

Answer (score 63, accepted):

See [this quote from Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot):

> Operator . (dot) could in principle be overloaded using the same
>   technique as used for ->. However, doing so can lead to questions
>   about whether an operation is meant for the object overloading . or an
>   object referred to by . For example:
>
> ```
> class Y {
> public:
>     void f();
>     // ...
> };
>
> class X {    // assume that you can overload .
>     Y* p;
>     Y& operator.() { return *p; }
>     void f();
>     // ...
> };
>
> void g(X& x)
> {
>     x.f();    // X::f or Y::f or error?
> }
> ```
>
> This problem can be solved in several ways. At the time of
>   standardization, it was not obvious which way would be best. For more
>   details, see [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html).

Comment: Full quote from TDaEoC++ in my answer.

Comment: I am tempted to vote this down for plagiarism/recoloring. When quoting, quote verbatim, don't tweak. And use the quote formats.

Comment: The example is just overload resolution ambiguity, pointing to a need for more careful programming ( see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554606/ambiguity-not-picked-up-by-compiler ) This situation should not serve as a reason to not overload `operator .`

Comment: @slashmais No. The justification of `operator.` is an explicit parallel with `operator->`. And how could you do overloading resolution?

Comment: Just to note that later on, Bjarne Stroustrup was in favor of _operator dot_ and even pushed a proposal for that, which apparently was not (yet) accepted: [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf) - as already added by @emlai as a comment to the question

Comment: Here's a later version of the proposal: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf

Comment: Here's a competing proposal for solving many of the same problems, which tries to use a special form of inheritance instead of overloading the dot operator: https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0352r1.pdf

Answer (score 52):

Stroustrup said C++ should be an extensible, but not mutable language.

The dot (attribute access) operator was seen as too close to the core of the language to allow overloading.

See [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.google.com/search?q=The+Design+and+Evolution+of+C%2B%2B), page 242, section *11.5.2 Smart References*.

> When I decided to allow overloading of operator `->`, I naturally considered whether operator `.` could be similarly overloaded.
>
> At the time, I considered the following arguments conclusive: If `obj` is a class object then `obj.m` has a meaning for every member `m` of that object's class. We try not to make the language mutable by redefining built-in operations (though that rule is violated for `=` out of dire need, and for unary `&`).
>
> If we allowed overloading of `.` for a class `X`, we would be unable to access members of `X` by normal means; we would have to use a pointer and `->`, but `->` and `&` might also have been re-defined. I wanted an extensible language, not a mutable one.
>
> These arguments are weighty, but not conclusive. In particular, in 1990 Jim Adcock proposed to allow overloading of operator `.` *exactly* the way operator `->` is.

The "I" in this quote is Bjarne Stroustrup. You cannot be more authoritative than that.

If you want to really understand C++ (as in "why is it this way"), you should absolutely read this book.

Comment: As is pointed out in other comments, Stroustrup has apparently changed his mind on this issue and has himself presented (in 2016) a proposal for allowing overloaded operator ".". See https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup for some of his comments on why he did so.

Answer (score 28):

Stroustrup  [has an answer for this question](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot):

> Operator . (dot) could in principle be
>   overloaded using the same technique as
>   used for ->. However, doing so can
>   lead to questions about whether an
>   operation is meant for the object
>   overloading . or an object referred to
>   by . For example:
>
> ```
> class Y {
> public:
>     void f();
>     // ...
> };
> class X {   // assume that you can overload .
>     Y* p;
>     Y& operator.() { return *p; }
>     void f();
>     // ...
> };
> void g(X& x)
> {
>     x.f();  // X::f or Y::f or error?
> }
> ```
>
> This problem can be solved in several
>   ways. At the time of standardization,
>   it was not obvious which way would be
>   best. For more details, see [D&E](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html).

Comment: See my comment on Anton's answer

Comment: Note this recent proposal by Stroustrup on allowing overloaded operator ".": http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to understand, if you go through the internal mechanism of operator function invocation,
Say a class complex can have two member r for real part and i for imaginary part.
Say **Complex C1(10,20),C2(10,2)** // we assume there is an already a two argument constructor within class.
Now if you write **C1+C2** as a statement then compiler try to find the overloaded version of + operator on complex number. Now we assume that I overload + operator, so
**C1+C2** internally translated as **c1.operator+(c2)**
Now assume for the time beings you can overload '.' operator.
so now think following call **C1.disp()**//display content of a complex object Now try to represent as an internal representation 
**C1.operator.(------)** , completely messy things created. That is the reason why we can't overload '.' operator

Comment: Some people say internal translated should not call overloaded `operator.`

Comment: See a C++ proposal for how this can be useful and not so messy: [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf)

Comment: Here's a later version of the proposal: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf

Comment: Here's a competing proposal for solving many of the same problems, which tries to use a special form of inheritance instead of overloading the dot operator: https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0352r1.pdf