# Is there a way to replace string ">" with > in an 'if' condition?

Tags: c++

I came across the below use case, but I could not find a proper solution.
Is there a way to replace string "<" or ">" with condition `<` or `>` in an `if` condition?

Example:

```
  string condition = "<";
  if (10 condition 8)   // Here I want to replace condition with <
  {
      // Some code
  }
```

I don't want to do it like:

```
if ("<" == condition)
{
   if (10 < 8)
   {
   }
}
else if (">" == condition)
{
   if (10 > 10)
   {
   }
}
```

And my condition will change during run time. I am just searching for a simple way if exist apart from above.

Use case: The user will give some query like below:

```
input: 10 > 9   =>  output: true
input: 10 < 7   =>  output: false
```

Basically I need to parse this query, as I have these 3 words (10, >, 9) as strings, and somehow I want to convert string ">" or "<" to actual symbol `>` or `<`.

Comment: No.  Also note that "string" is not a C type.

Comment: You can do `#define lessThan <` and then write `if (10 lessThan 8)`. This is probably useless but you didn't mention an actual use case either.

Comment: @melpomene your suggestion is irrelevant, as `lessthen` is just the identifier name he use for the operand...
`#define` will result in pre-compile time and won't change between runs.

Comment: @TomerW Changes between runs wasn't part of the requirements. Besides, why would it be called `lessThan` if it could represent other operations than `<`?

Comment: Are there other string representations of the standard operators that you want to be able to process?

Comment: I edited the question with more info, please have a look.

Comment: can you change your language? lets say C#? java? python?

Comment: Solution searching for problem?

Comment: @Olaf what do you mean by "Solution searching for problem?"

Answer (score 5):

You can map the string to a standard library comparator functor such as `std::less` via a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Yes, but this involves using the preprocessor, so you couldn't use the value of a string as a dynamically set operator like in the asker's example. This is an interesting strategy to consider, though, as it could make things look a little easier to read.

Comment: The preprocessor does not need to be used for this.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Sorry, I don't understand how you arrive at your conclusion. There's no preprocessor involved.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create a new operator in C++ (*[Can I create a new operator in C++ and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425077/can-i-create-a-new-operator-in-c-and-how)*). I can see where you are coming from with this idea, but the language just doesn't support that. You can, however, create a function that takes two operands and a string "argument" and returns the appropriate value.

```
bool CustomCompare(int operand1, int operand2, string op)
{
    if (op == "<")
    {
        return operand1<operand2;
    }
    if (op == ">")
    {
        return operand1>operand2;
    }
    if (op == "_")
    {
        return DoTheHokeyPokeyAndTurnTheOperandsAround(operand1, operand2);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I told, I have thought about It but looking if there is a another way. just like token pasting operators

Answer (score 3):

```
std::function<bool(int,int)> comparator = std::less;
if(comparator(10, 8))
{
    //some code
}
```

See Also:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Answer (score 0):

If you are a C++ Ninja, and you are very stubborn to get it working just the way you wish, there is a way, but it is advanced and complicated.

I mostly write [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) code for [VxWorks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks), but I guess it can be done for any other.

Let's say you have: `string myExpression = "mySize > minSize";`

1. "Rebuild the String as a C code" (save to file, use `ccppc`, `gcc`, `gpp`, whatever toolchain you have.)
2. You need to link it with your code, at least to get ELF relocations for `mySize` & `minSize` (I think it can be done using app-load, if you customize your `ld` command.
3. Load the code using `ld`
4. Jump to the new address you loaded your code to.

All that said, I would not recommend you to do that:

1. Very complicated.
2. Not the most stable, and very bug/error prone.
3. Can lead to major vulnerabilities "Hacker" style,
   and proper sanitation is required.

The only pro I can see, is that this method supports everything **C** has to offer out of the box! BitWise, +-/*^!, even functions as pow(), and such.

A little bit better is:

To compile a function as:

```
`"bool comparer_AB(int a, int b) { return a " + operator + "}"`
```

and then call `comparer_AB();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using operation = std::function<bool(int,int)>;
  std::map<std::string, operation> mp = 
    {{"<", std::less<int>()}, 
     {">", std::greater<int>()}};

  int x = 5; 
  int y = 10;
  std::string op = "<";

  bool answer = mp[op](x, y);
}
```