# Type conversion from an expression to a double in C++ write a new operator**?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, overloading

There is a generic class Vector which extends std::array, and a generic class Expression which defines the possible expressions of the Vectors.

For example:

Vector A({1,2,3});

Vector B({2,2,2});

and the expressions:

A + B;

A * B;

A - B;

A / B;

Now I need this expression A ** B which returns a double as the scalar-production of two vectors A and B, the result must be: 2+4+6=12. The problem is the implementation of operator**!!!

How can i write this operator** ?

My Idea is to overload the dereference operator* of Vector which returns a pointer and then overload the struct-Mul oder multiply operator* ... couldn't solve this error:

"no suitable conversion function from "Expression, Mul, Vector *>" to "double" exists"

```
template<typename Left, typename Op, typename Right> class Expression {
    const Left& m_left;
    const Right& m_right;

public:
    typedef typename Left::value_type value_type;

    // Standard constructor
    Expression(const Left& l, const Right& r) : m_left{ l }, m_right{ r } {}

    size_t size() const {
        return m_left.size();
    }

    value_type operator[](int i) const {
        return Op::apply(m_left[i], m_right[i]);
    }
};

struct Mul {
    template<typename T> static T apply(T l, T r) {
        return l * r;
    }
};

template<typename Left, typename Right>
Expression<Left, Mul, Right> operator*(const Left& l, const Right& r) {
    return Expression<Left, Mul, Right>(l, r);
}

.......................

// Class Vector extends std::array
template<class T, size_t S> class Vector : public array<T, S> {

public:
    // Standard constructor
    Vector<T, S>(array<T, S>&& a) : array<T, S>(a) {}

    // Initializerlist constructor
    Vector(const initializer_list<T>& data) {
        size_t s = __min(data.size(), S);
        auto it = data.begin();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
            this->at(i) = *it++;
    }
};

.....................................

int main {

    Vector<double, 5> A({ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    Vector<double, 5> B({ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 });
    Vector<double, 5> C;
    C = A * B; // is a Vector: [6, 9, 12, 15, 18] and it works.

    double d = A**B;  // but this one does not work, the error message is: "no suitable conversion function from "Expression<Vector<double, 5U>, Mul, Vector<double, 5U> *>" to "double" exists"

    cout << d << endl; // must give me: 60
}
```

Comment: That would be almost impossible you are better off overloading another operator like the right shift or !

Comment: there is no `operator**` in C++.

Comment: You can't use the `**` *notation* because C++ doesn't have a `**` operator, and doesn't support defining entirely new operators. You can overload the ordinary single `*` if you want. Or you can define a pseudo-operator like `%dot%`, an abuse of notation where the first `%` invokes an overload of `%` for your vector and the type of `dot`, producing some result that then is passed to an overload of `%` again, with the second vector. But why not consider a simple **named function**? Simple and maintainable.

Comment: KIA another way would be to use the dereference operator and multiplication operator on perhaps a private type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a new operator in C++ and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425077/can-i-create-a-new-operator-in-c-and-how)

Comment: I know there is not an operator**, but i want to combine multiply operator* and dereference operator* as one operator**!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I was able to come up with that is very quick and easy to follow is:

```
class X
{
  class B
  {

  };
  B n;
public:

    B operator* ()
    {
        return this->n;
    }

    double operator * (B rhs)
    {
        cout<<"Here"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X a;
    X b;

    a ** b;
}
```

This allows you store the data in the B class and then use it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of type abuse gives you want you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct special_vector;

struct star
{
    star(special_vector& v) : vec(std::addressof(v)) {}

    special_vector* vec;
};

struct special_vector : std::vector<double>
{
    using std::vector<double>::vector;

    auto operator*() -> star { return star(*this);}
};


auto operator*(special_vector const& l, star const& r) -> double
{
    assert(l.size() == r.vec->size());

    double result = 0.0;

    auto fl = l.cbegin(), fr = r.vec->cbegin(), ll = l.cend();
    while (fl != ll)
    {
        result += (*fl++ * *fr++);
    }

    return result;    
}


int main()
{
    auto v1 = special_vector{ 1, 2, 3 };
    auto v2 = special_vector{ 1, 2, 3 };

    auto ans = v1 ** v2;

    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

> 14

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f831c7594421f37d