# Python rise to the power ** operator in C++

Tags: python, c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, implementation

Is this possible to implement the `**` operator for C++ for two numbers of integer types?

```cpp
int main(){
  int a = 6;
  int b = 2;
  int result = a**b;
}
```

Comment: Sure, if you're on the standards committee, otherwise no.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425096/8372853) on the duplicate target.