# C++ Multiple Possible Value Control Flow

Tags: c++

Currently using C++20, GCC 11.1.0

I'm coding for simple movement in a game loop.

Following the abstract pseudocode below, how would I be able to translate this into code? I was thinking of using either `goto` to just skip right into the scope that uses the values, or `std::optional` to check whether the values exist or not.

The reason I'm trying to do this instead of just adding the bottom if statement into the A...D if statements is because the bottom if statement could become very large, and may add redundancy. Or should I just refactor the if statement into a separate function?

```
if (direction is left && ...)
{
    int xVelocity {left_calculation...};
}

else if (direction is right && ...)
{
    int xVelocity {right_calculation...};
}

else if (direction is up && ...)
{
    int yVelocity {up_calculation...};
}

else if (direction is down && ...)
{
    int yVelocity {down_calculation...};
}


if (x has a value or y has a value)
{
    // Do something with those values...
}
```

Comment: What does "most efficient" mean? Can you define what "most efficient" means to you, in objective, concrete terms. Otherwise this is purely opinion-based, which would not be an appropriate question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Note: You can't declare a variable, `int x {A_x_calculation...};`, inside the scope of the `if` and use it outside the `if`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C++ have some equivalent of SQL coalesce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339549/does-c-have-some-equivalent-of-sql-coalesce)

Comment: @user4581301 I did it intentionally to show that `x` and `y` are initialized in those if statements. If I initialize it outside then they will always have a value (default 0)

Comment: You could pack the processing code up into a function and call the function as needed inside the various `if` statements that determine the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Before you use `goto`, consider [this](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/292:_goto)

Comment: In order to be able to advise, we'd need to know if `A_x_calculation` and `B_x_calculation`, etc. are essentially the same logic applied to `A`, `B`, etc. respectively, or if those are distinct logics.

Comment: @user4581301 yea that seems like the best option so far

Comment: @anastaciu I know, which is why I was hesitant on using `goto`

Comment: The next thing is to explain what "x has a value and/or y has a value" mean. It seems that the pseudocode either sets both x and y, on some code path, or doesn't. How does x wind up with a value, but not y, or vice versa?

Comment: Please clarify: What behaviour do you want if the A case and the C case both enter?

Comment: I've edited the post further. Basically the four if statements cover the four possible directions my game character can move, and based on the direction, x and y represent the velocity of the game character.

Comment: Still unclear. Can you go down and right at the same time?

Comment: No, you can only move in one direction

Comment: Then this boils down to a simple `switch` statement, where each branch sets `x` and `y`. and the rest is history. There are not that many different ways to boil an egg, that can be compared against each other to determine which one is more "efficient", in some unclear manner.

Comment: OK. Try this: Make a function that takes `x` and `y` by reference and returns `bool`. Put the `if` statements in this function. Each if ends with a `return true;`. If the end of the function is reached, `return false;` Back in the main function you have something like `if (the_func(x,y)) {do stuff }`

Comment: @user4581301 That could work, thanks

Comment: How do you expect to interpret a single boolean to select one of four alternative code paths, that you've described?

Comment: Like [VikingOfValhalla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73348361/3135317) suggested, I'd *DEFINITELY* consider using a [switch()/case](https://www.guru99.com/c-switch-case-statement.html) block if at all possible.  It's efficient, it supports handling the same "response" for multiple different cases (e.g. up or down, or right or left).

Answer (score 0):

You can represent optionality via `std::option`:

```
std::optional xVelocityOpt =
    direction == left  ? std::make_optional(left_calculation)
  : direction == right ? std::make_optional(right_calculation)
                       : {};

std::optional yVelocityOpt =
    direction == up    ? std::make_optional(up_calculation)
  : direction == down  ? std::make_optional(down_calculation)
                       : {};

if (xVelocityOpt || yVelocityOpt)
{
    // you can use the actual values as
    // *xVelocityOpt and *yVelocityOpt
    // ...
}
```

... but I'd also consider using simple `int` velocities and represent empty as `0` (if what you mean by the variables are delta v in physics).

Answer (score 0):

If instead of x,y you use delta_x,delta_y for relative value change then your problem solves itself. Then your if is just:

```
int delta_x = 0;
int delta_y = 0;
...
if( delta_x | delta_y )
  on_xy_changed(old_x + delta_x, old_y + delta_y);
```