# Ambiguity not picked up by compiler

Tags: c++, ambiguity

I had to spent some time in finding and fixing a bug that I managed to isolate in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    std::string S;
    A(const std::string s) { S = s; }
};

void f1(A a) { std::cout << "f1:a.S = " << a.S << "\n"; }
void f1(const std::string s) { std::cout << "f1:s = " << s << "\n"; }

void f2(A a) { std::cout << "f2:a.S = " << a.S << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    f1(A("test"));
    f1(std::string("test"));

    f2(A("test"));
    f2(std::string("test"));

    return 0;
}
```

The bug was caused by the overlooked (by me and the compiler(?)) ambiguity created by the `f1`-function: `f2` clearly shows that both `f1(A)` and `f1(std::string)` apply to `A`, but when compiled the ambiguity is not picked-up by the compiler, and when executed the output is:

```
f1:a.S = test
f1:s = test
f2:a.S = test
f2:a.S = test
```

Is this behavior correct? Compiler problem? Or just plain old PIBCAK?

Comment: @Mat: Yes, the problem occurs when I call `f1(std::string)` expecting `A` and not getting it :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior that you describe is expected:  there is no ambiguity.  An overload resolution ambiguity occurs when two overloads match equally well and are both "the best overload."

When you call `f1` with an argument of type `A`, the first `f1` is an exact match; the second `f1` does not match at all.  Thus, `f1` obviously wins during overload resolution.

When you call `f1` with an argument of type `std::string`, the first `f1` matches via the converting constructor of `A`; the second `f1` is an exact match.  The second `f1` is a better match:  it's an exact match and no conversion is required.  The two overloads do not match equally well, thus there is no ambiguity.  The second `f1` wins during overload resolution.

Comment: "it's an exact match and no conversion is required": it's an exact match, yes, but a (standard) conversion needs to be done, in this case a qualification conversion.

Comment: @ipc:  No qualification conversion is required.  Top-level cv-qualifiers are not part of the type of a function and thus have no effect on overload resolution.

Comment: @slashmais:  Overload resolution is fraught with subtleties.

Comment: The fact that a function's arguments' cv-qualifications are not part of its signature is because they aren't relevant to callers. The arguments are just local variables initialised during the call and only available within the body. So, one should never apply `const`-qualification to arguments in function declarations, only definitions - as this means you can change whether or not the argument is `const` in the latter without feeling obliged to update the former to match, forcing your users to recompile. (It makes no difference in terms of ABI, but `make` _et al._ don't take that into account)