# C++ Operator overloading: assign A's attribute value of type B to a B object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The std::string class allows assigning its internal value from different types, such as 'char', 'const char*' and 'std::string', with the help of [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) operator. Which operator is needed to be overloaded in order to achieve the following?

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::string value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

    // A a = std::string("some value")
    A& operator=(const std::string value) {
        m_value = value;
    }

    // std::string someValue = A("blabla")
    ???? operator ????

private:
    std::string m_value;
};
```

After that, we should be able to access std::string's functions through the A object, for example:

```
A a("foo");

printf("A's value: %s \n", a.c_str());
```

Comment: not related to your question, but `m_value = value;` should be `m_value = std::move(value);`, and `value` should be non-const. similarly for the constructor

Comment: @M.M why should std::move() be used in this case?

Comment: So that the resources held by `value` can be transferred to `m_value`, instead of making a copy and then destroying the old resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it possible for `class A` to convert itself to type `string`.

This looks like:

```
class A
{
public:
    operator std::string() const { return m_value; }
};
```

After that, you can do this:

```
printf("A's value: %s \n", ((std::string)a).c_str());
```

---

Alternately, you can overload the `->` operator:

```
class A
{
public:
    const std::string* operator->()const { return & m_value; }
}

printf("A's value: %s \n", a->c_str());
```

[***IDEOne link***](http://ideone.com/LPfIV3)

Comment: thats almost exactly what I'm looking for. I'm aware of the "operator std::string" (whats the name of this operator by the way?) but casting it to a std::string is really weird. The "->" operator almost does what I really need. Isnt it possible to override the "." operator (which one is this?) so that we could do "a.c_str()" and no pointers would be used/returned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520035/why-cant-you-overload-the-operator-in-c