# Reassignable reference in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a reference field that needs to be reassigned. But unlike pointer, it can't be null.

Requirements:

- Reference syntax: `field.foo()` to invoke method, instead of `field->foo();`
- Re-assignable:  `foo = new_val;  // OK`

Is it possible to model model this concept in C++?

Comment: You can't reassign the reference.

Comment: References are bound at initialization time and cannot be reseated.

Comment: You haven't said why you think you need to do this  - sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @Ron I know this for sure. But is it possible to write smart template that works like reference?

Comment: I'm sure you could wrap up a pointer in a class to _look_ a bit like a reference. But why would you want to??

Comment: @NathanOliver Agree. Duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Use a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` instead of a raw reference.

Comment: Thanks. Did now known about it! Unfortunately it' not possible to call a method without a .get()

Comment: Looks like it's not possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520035/why-cant-you-overload-the-operator-in-c

Comment: Yep.  If `get()` is a deal breaker, then you're out-of-luck.  Mind you, `reference_wrapper` is implicitly convertible to the associated reference type, so you can often avoid the `get()` in practice.

Comment: Seem to be a well known problem in C++ : https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup